# Using vue.js with Phoenix failed so far

Tags: vue.js, elixir, phoenix-framework

I follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@jespr/create-a-simple-chat-web-app-using-phoenix-and-vue-js-bc5d82e53f9b) to learn to use vue.js in a Phoenix web app.
So far I made until I should get the word **Vuechat** in browser, but I didn't. Instead I got error message in iex console like below:

```
05 May 13:19:52 - info: compiling
05 May 13:19:54 - error: Resolving deps of web\static\js\app.js failed. Could not load module 'my-app.vue' from 'c:\Users\sadmin\Documents\Elixir\vuechat\web\static\js'. Possible solution: add 'my-app.vue' to package.json and `npm install`.
```

I thought I did everything according to that tutorial, but still not getting it works. I don't know much about using **brunch** or **npm** too, so please help

Location of my-app.vue is shows in below image

[image]

P.S. I'm working under Windows 10 os and using Visual Studio Code

Thanks.

Comment: Check your path: component `my-app.vue` should be here `web/static/components/` if you include it like in tutorial with path `../components/my-app.vue`

Comment: Could you show us the `import` line you have for `my-app.vue` ? Also, do you use vue-cli webpack config?

Comment: @Elfayer Im not using webpack ... using brunch (following the tutorial)

Comment: @BromoProgrammer Souldn't it be an `_` instead of a `-`? (in your file name) Also it seems that you import from `static\js`, while your component is in `static\components`, or is this path from a build stage? Can you show us the inclusion code of `my_app.vue` in `app.js`?

Comment: @Elfayer ... you are correct ... :D ... its typo error ... thanks :D